# Spring Boot 3 Migration issue with generic JPA Query

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

It seems the generics functionallity is no more supported in hibernate 6

my base repositoy class

```
@NoRepositoryBean
public interface AbstractBusinessUnitJpaRepository<T extends AbstractBusinessUnitJpaEntity, 
                                       ID extends Serializable> 
        extends JpaRepository<T, ID> {
    
    long countByTenantAndBusinessUnitIdIn(Long tenant,List<Long> businessUnitIds);

    T findByIdAndTenantAndBusinessUnitIdIn(ID id,Long tenant,List<Long> businessUnitIds);
    
    T findByTenantAndBusinessUnitIdAndId(Long tenant,Long businessUnitId, ID id);
    
}
```

actual repositories extends this repo ex:

```
@Repository
public interface UserJpaRepository extends AbstractBusinessUnitJpaRepository<UserJpaEntity, Long> {
}
```

the method was working in spring boot 2 and hibernate 5
but after upgrading to Boot 3 and hibernate 6

i am getting

```
AbstractBusinessUnitJpaRepository.findByIdAndTenantAndBusinessUnitIdIn(java.io.Serializable,java.lang.Long,java.util.List); Cannot compare left expression of type 'java.lang.Long' with right expression of type 'java.io.Serializable'
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.PartTreeJpaQuery.<init>(PartTreeJpaQuery.java:107)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$CreateQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:124)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$CreateIfNotFoundQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:258)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$AbstractQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:95)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lookupQuery(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:111)
    ... 140 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.query.SemanticException: Cannot compare left expression of type 'java.lang.Long' with right expression of type 'java.io.Serializable'
    at org.hibernate.query.sqm.internal.TypecheckUtil.assertComparable(TypecheckUtil.java:358)
    at org.hibernate.query.sqm.tree.predicate.SqmComparisonPredicate.<init>(SqmComparisonPredicate.java:48)
    at org.hibernate.query.sqm.tree.predicate.SqmComparisonPredicate.<init>(SqmComparisonPredicate.java:34)
    at org.hibernate.query.sqm.internal.SqmCriteriaNodeBuilder.equal(SqmCriteriaNodeBuilder.java:2121)
    at org.hibernate.query.sqm.internal.SqmCriteriaNodeBuilder.equal(SqmCriteriaNodeBuilder.java:192)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryCreator$PredicateBuilder.build(JpaQueryCreator.java:312)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryCreator.toPredicate(JpaQueryCreator.java:210)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryCreator.create(JpaQueryCreator.java:121)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryCreator.create(JpaQueryCreator.java:60)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.AbstractQueryCreator.createCriteria(AbstractQueryCreator.java:119)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.AbstractQueryCreator.createQuery(AbstractQueryCreator.java:95)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.AbstractQueryCreator.createQuery(AbstractQueryCreator.java:81)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.PartTreeJpaQuery$QueryPreparer.<init>(PartTreeJpaQuery.java:218)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.PartTreeJpaQuery$CountQueryPreparer.<init>(PartTreeJpaQuery.java:361)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.PartTreeJpaQuery.<init>(PartTreeJpaQuery.java:102)
    ... 144 more
```

Comment: This is a [Hibernate bug](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-17454). 
 What is the Spring Boot version?  Spring Boot 3.2.1 [upgraded Hibernate](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/releases/tag/v3.2.1) to a version that includes the fix for the bug.